# CSV file thousand seperators

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a list of lists containing only floats to a .csv file. Currently, the floats show thousand seperators (e.g. 1500.0 becomes 15.000) which is an issue.

This is code which reproduces the problem:

```
arr = np.random.rand(10,10) # making array of 10x10 with random numbers
arr = arr*1000000 # multiplying times a million
arr_list = arr.tolist() # converting to a list of lists

# writing to a .csv file
with open("arr_list.csv", "w", encoding = 'UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(arr_list)
```

How do I turn this off, while keeping the decimal seperator?
I'm unsure if the problem occurs in Python or Excel.

PS: I added a link to a screenshot of what the .csv file values look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/we8ZD.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side-note: Make sure to pass `newline=''` (empty string) to your `open` call; the `csv` module expects to have control over line-endings to match the dialect, `newline=''` turns off line ending translation. If you want to confirm whether Python or Excel is at fault, try opening it in a plain text editor? I'm a little confused as to the thousands separators being there at all, neither Python nor the `csv` module should be inserting them unless you explicitly format them with `,` in the format spec.

Comment: @ShadowRanger most likely Excel's default regional/locale settings

Comment: You really should show us the contents of the actual file, not a screenshot from excel. What does `cat arr_list.csv | head` show you (assuming you are on *nix)?

Comment: Places where I have seen this before are in data where the locales differ. For example, when working with data from Europe I have seen `,` in the numbers. This caused all scripts to break since the export would use `,` and import scripts assumed U.S. locale which didn't handle the 1000th separator in the strings.

Comment: Is it only for Excel? If yes, have you considered pandas and `to_excel` - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html ?

Comment: @MYousefi but that is almost certainly an issue with the settings in excel. The Python code above would not add that sort of formatting to the csv file.

Comment: @margusl how would that affect the way excel is printing those numbers?

Comment: I don't know the exact details but I feel it could be similar if the code/library is locale aware. It could be causing issues similar to timezone aware vs not in date times.

Comment: This is an Excel setting. If you open the csv file in a text editor like notepad, you'll see there are no thousands separators, only decimal separators.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It seems you are correct. I can't find any reference to locale in the python `csv` module documentation.

Comment: @MYousefi right, the `csv` module simply defers to `str` to format non-str objects, if you want them formatted in a particular way, you must implement that yourself

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , embedding datatypes do have some positive side effects - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNPgw.png .  My locale uses `,` for decimal separator, on the right there's csv from generated by posted snippet in Colab (decimal_point = `.`). Pandas xlsx output, same env, no locale-related tweaking.

Comment: @margusl I don't understand what you are talking about. Again, this seems like an issue with Excel, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , my question was is the resulting CSV only meant to be opened in Excel as it seemed to be OPs first choice to check the file.  If yes, there's no need to deal with locale-specific bits and just export it as xlsx.